# Docker distinguish multistage-stage from registry image in FROM clause

Tags: docker, docker-multi-stage-build

In the docker-docs for the FROM the following sentence is given (highlighting by me):

> Optionally a name can be given to a new build stage by adding AS name to the FROM instruction. The name can be used in **subsequent FROM** and COPY --from= <name|index> instructions to refer to the image built in this stage.

While there are many blog posts and descriptions about the second case (with `COPY --from`), there is not much said about the first one (`FROM ⟨previous stage⟩`.

So what behaviour should one expect if a build stage is called the same way as an image in a registry?

I'm asking specifically for documentation and/or source references, because just trying it out is not very helpful and may change in the future (source code may too, but at least there is a referenced blob that someone can easily see as being changed).

Example:

```
FROM trinitronx/python-simplehttpserver as node
RUN bash -c 'echo hello world > index.html'

FROM node
RUN echo $PWD
```

It seems like we are in the previous stage then, but how can someone then explicitly state and/or see wether the image is from the registry or from a previous stage?

Comment: You should really include a tag in your `FROM` line when you are pulling from a registry. Don't use `latest` if you have a choice and don't depend on the tag automatically expanding `latest`.

Comment: I know what I should, but this case is ambigous and i was asking how to disambiguate… actually your comment is part of the answer. If I put a tag in the second `FROM`, it's clear it refers to registry image, but how to explicitly state that the `FROM` refers to a previous stage? (compare to `COPY --from…` where it is clear that another stage is referenced)